# How to cast between pointers freely in C, for a generic memory pool?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-pool

I am beginning to implement a generic memory pool. This is for learning purposes so, there are tons of mistakes definitely. But, I was moving forward. Now I am stucked at a new part. First, the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } BOOL;

typedef struct mem_block {
    uint8_t* data;
    size_t block_size;
    size_t pool_position;
    BOOL is_freed;
} mem_block;

typedef struct mem_pool {
    mem_block* blocks;
    size_t index;
    size_t pool_size;
} mem_pool;

mem_pool *pool_init() {
    mem_pool *pool = (mem_pool *) malloc(sizeof(mem_pool));
    pool->pool_size = (size_t) 128;
    mem_block* blk = (mem_block *) malloc(pool->pool_size * sizeof (mem_block));
    pool->index = 0;
    pool->blocks = blk;

    return pool;
}

void *pool_allocate(mem_pool **pool, size_t size) {
    mem_pool* _pool = *pool;
    size_t free_portion = _pool->pool_size - _pool->index;

    if(size < free_portion){
        mem_block* allocated_blk = _pool->blocks + _pool->index;
        uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*) malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
        allocated_blk->data = data;
        allocated_blk->block_size = size;
        allocated_blk->is_freed = FALSE;
        allocated_blk->pool_position = _pool->index;
        _pool->index += size; 
        return (void *) allocated_blk->data;
    }
    else{
        printf("Pool is out of memory");
        return NULL;
    }
}

/*void pool_free(mem_pool **pool, void *block) {
    mem_block* cur = (mem_block*) block;
    mem_block* next = cur + 1;
    // override the unneeded memory
memmove(cur, next, (*pool)->pool_size - next->pool_position);
}*/

typedef struct complex {
    double i;
    double r;
} complex;

mem_pool *GLOBAL_POOL = pool_init();
int main() {
    complex *c1 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c1->r = 1.0;
    c1->i = 2.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c1->r, c1->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size -   GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    complex *c2 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c2->r = 2.0;
    c2->i = 3.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c2->r, c2->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    mem_block* cur = (mem_block *) &c2;
    printf("Position of c2 is %ld\n", cur->pool_position);
    printf("Adress of c2's block is %x\n", cur);
    printf("Address of c2 is %x\n", &c2);
    printf("c2 points to %x\n", c2);

    complex *c3 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c3->r = 3.0;
    c3->i = 4.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c3->r, c3->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    cur = (mem_block *) &c3;
    printf("Position of c3 is %ld\n", cur->pool_position);
    printf("Adress of c3's block is %x\n", cur);
    printf("Address of c3 is %x\n", &c3);
    printf("c3 points to %x\n", c3);

    complex *c4 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c4->r = 4.0;
    c4->i = 5.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c4->r, c4->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    complex *c5 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c5->r = 5.0;
    c5->i = 6.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c5->r, c5->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    complex *c6 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c6->r = 6.0;
    c6->i = 7.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c6->r, c6->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    complex *c7 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    c7->r = 7.0;
    c7->i = 8.0;
    printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c7->r, c7->i);
    printf("Remaining free size is %ld\n", GLOBAL_POOL->pool_size - GLOBAL_POOL->index);

    complex *c8 = (complex *) pool_allocate(&GLOBAL_POOL, sizeof(complex));
    if(c8 != NULL) {
        c8->r = 3.0;
        c8->i = 4.0;
        printf("Value is (%f + %fi)\n", c8->r, c8->i);
    }else {
        return -1;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For now, its size is 128 bytes but once I get the basics, I will make it of unlimited size. Allocation probably works OK, you can see the output and see that I can set the allocated pointers and use the value. On top of this, I wanted to implement `free`. It is in commented out function `pool_free`. To perform `memmove`, I need to know the index of the `mem_block` I am deleting.

In the `pool_allocate`, you can see that I return the `data` pointer of the allocated block, not the whole thing so that it can be used similar to regular `malloc`. This means, when freeing, I need to recover `mem_block` from the data pointer. To be able to do this, I put the `data` pointer as the first element of a `mem_block`.

Let me explain further on the code

```
mem_block* cur = (mem_block *) &c3;
printf("Position of c3 is %ld\n", cur->pool_position);
printf("Adress of c3's block is %x\n", cur);
printf("Address of c3 is %x\n", &c3);
printf("c3 points to %x\n", c3);
```

`c3` here is allocated using `pool_allocate` and resulting pointer to data, `uint8_t*` in reality was casted to `complex *` to be used. So `c3` points to a `complex` object. Dereferencing should give the actual data, and I think this works. But it also has its own address. I supposed this address is the same as `data` pointer of its block since it is the first member in a `mem_block`. So I casted it freely to a `mem_block*`. But this does not work.

```
printf("Position of c3 is %ld\n", cur->pool_position);
```

says `Position of c3 is 0` or other gibberish. I am expecting to see things like 16, 32 etc. since each `mem_block` is 16 bytes. So, why do you think the cast

```
mem_block* cur = (mem_block *) &c3;
```

won't let me work with `c3` as if it is a `mem_block`? Maybe I am failing to correctly pass a pointer by reference so that changes to pointed things are not visible outside? This seems unlikely, since I can work with allocated objects as expected but who knows? I checked every part but still could not solve the issue.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `cur` to contain? Your cast basically takes 8-bytes which constitute the `complex` struct and tries to interpret it as a much bigger `mem_block` struct instead (with incompatible layout and types), resulting it gibberish values of fields.

Comment: `c3` is not `mem_block`, but `mem_block->data`.

Comment: Also, it'd be much better if you remove everything from your code and leave [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) only. In particular, the whole memory pool thing looks irrelevant as you're only concerned with a specific cast.

Comment: `c3` is a local variable - its location, `&c3`, is not an address in your pool. Its value, `c3`, is.

Comment: You use too much casting. It prevents compiler from warning you about invalid conversions (which you have a lot). Most, if not all, casts also seem to be completely unnecessary.

Comment: @yeputons I try to make `cur` point to allocated `mem_block` where `c3` is the data pointer. OK, I'll look into MCVE.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling this in C? A conformant C compiler should choke on `mem_pool *GLOBAL_POOL = pool_init();`, because dynamic initialization of global variables is a C++ thing. And in the other side, casting `malloc` is useless (and frowned upon) in C.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh, I understood my mistake thanks to your clarification. Now, I will try to find a way. But, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to achieve? I guess not as things are as they are.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I will look into not casting `malloc`. I indeed compile this with a C++ compiler but I will change it when I am at home and try with a C compiler.

Comment: And you're not returning a pointer to a `mem_block` from the allocation function, so using it as one is undefined. Sit down and draw your pool and all the pointers pointers on a piece of paper and figure out what you really want to do.

Comment: You can't deduce from the *value* of `allocated_blk->data` which `mem_block`, if any, it might be stored in. Think about this for a minute or two: I write down my friend's address on a page in my address book. If I then tell you where they live, can you figure out which page I wrote it on?

Comment: @molbdnilo After you showed me, I am now basically returning the page I wrote on. The strange thing is, I can now cast returned `mem_block *` to a `complex *`. Things seem like OK. I guess, again, this is because `data` pointer is the first member. Any part of `mem_block` that can't fit in a pointer is just discarded?

Answer (score 1):

The way this works in malloc is that each block has a header (the management structure) and on alloc you return the address after that structure. Then on free you know you have the address after the header so you can compute the address of the actual header from that.

One simple trick for this is to use

```
void alloc(size_t size) {
    ...
    struct mem_block *block = <address of block you return>
    return &block[1];
}

void free(void *addr) {
    struct mem_block *block = addr;
    block[-1].is_freed = false;
    ...
}
```